# fubo tv - Kodi integration

Tags: video-streaming, kodi

I am using Kodi for almost anything. (https://kodi.tv/) I have a fubo.tv membership (https://www.fubo.tv/). It is a LEGAL streaming service for mainly soccer.

Right now I have to watch games through the fubo website. It's not working to my satisfaction.

Can someone please make these internet streams work in Kodi?

I am happy to donate for the work. I am online almost all the time and can assist. I can also provide all the details necessary.

Thank you very much.

Comment: to be clear: I don't need a Fubo-tv add-on. I don't even WANT it.

What I want is the channels fubo.tv offers to be in Kodi as if they were regular TV Channels.

No fancy add-on needed.

Someone will know how to do this for sure!

Comment: thank you, I tried that, but I can't make it work. I even see loads of m3u8 files in firefox. Like this one: https://fubotvuslive1-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/225111/BeInSportsENUS7/BeInSportsENUS7_VIDEO_1_4428000.m3u8
but it won't even play in VLC.
Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a addon name `script.game.rom.collection.browser`, you can use that instead and also you need to configure it.